# How to use module.exports in expressJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i was making this discord bot thing with discord js and i wanted to add some frontend to like change some things using website and not commands buut i cant or i just dont know how to
use module.exports in expressjs i tried some stuff like this

```
var server = website.listen(8080, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:%s", port);
});
```

and this

```
website.use('/vars.js', main)
```

but none of it works ;;-;

edit: I forgot to mention but "main" is module in vars.js

(code of vars.js)

```
module.exports = {
    "token": process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN,
    "creator": process.env.mainUserID,
    "creatorPing": "<@" + process.env.mainUserID + ">",
    "status": "Ay Bros",
    "version": "2.0.7"

}
```

next edit:
I dont really want to export functions from this file but variables, bacause functions cant change my bot status, i want to be able to modify the variables so my bot will change its status :P

Comment: In `main.js`: `module.exports = main`. In root file: `const main = require('./main.js')`

Comment: oh, sorry, i forgot to mention that main is module in vars.js

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to export your `main` function. You can do it these ways:

1. Using default export/import

```js
// vars.js
function main() {...}
module.exports = main;

// root file
const main = require('./vars.js');
website.use(main);
```

2. Using named export/import:

```js
// vars.js
function main() {...}
module.exports = { main };

// root file
const { main } = require('./vars.js');
website.use(main);
```

Another problem you have is wrong usage of `.use` function. It should receive a function, not a filename. So you need to import function and then use it, as I did in examples.

Comment: i didn't wanted to export functions but be able to export variables and modify them so i could change it via website

Comment: `const variables = require('./vars.js')`;

Comment: Yeaaaah: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at (index):16

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how to export the function you want but almost developer follows this pattern to exports functions in nodejs.

```
function getUser() {
    // Code here
}

function getUsers() {
    // Code here
}

module.exports = {
    getUser,
    getUsers
}
```

This would output:

```
getUser: [Function: getUser], getUsers: [Function: getUsers] }
```

This gives us function names and documents the API clearly at the end of the file and this pattern name is [revealing the module pattern](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/bb0eec99c02dda6aac0e041d0d4d7bf2).

Comment: but i wanted to not really export functions but variables

Comment: You can do like this 
//module.js
   var name='foobar';
   var city='xyz';
   var company='companyName';

   module.exports={
    name,
    city,
    company
  }
Usage

  // main.js
    require('./modules');
    console.log(name); // print 'foobar'